# Using Taylor's theorem show that $1 - \frac{x^2}{2} < \cos x < 1- \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Using Taylor's theorem show that 
$1-\frac{x^2}{2} < \cos x < 1-\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} \, \text{ for all } x \in \mathbb{R}$

I know this is true because of the Alternating series truncation error that alternates in sign, but is there a way to prove it?

Comment: Check $x = 0$, are you sure about strict inequalities?

Comment: It's definitely not true for *all* $x \in \mathbb{R}$:  $\cos (2 \pi) = 1 > 1 - (2 \pi)^2 / 2$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I don't see any problem with that

Comment: Alternating series remainder?

Comment: Whoops, you're right.  That's what I get for commenting before the coffee takes hold.

Answer (score 3):

As said in comments these are not strict inequalities, but I can show you how to obtain the second inequality :
With Taylor theorem (Lagrange version) we have :
$$\forall x \in \mathbb R, \exists c\in (0,1),  \cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}\cos''''(cx)=1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4c^4}{24}\cos(cx)$$
$$\cos(cx)\leq 1$$
$$\cos(x)\leq 1 -\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4c^4}{24}\leq 1 -\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{24}$$
You can apply the same kind of reasonning for the other inequality.

Comment: I would just point out one thing. The residue term should not have $c^4$ term in it. If we are writing Maclaurin Series of $f(x)$ then the residue term contains $f^{(n)} (\theta)$ where $0 < \theta < x$. Here you just happen to take $\theta = cx $ for some $0 <c <1$.

Answer (score 2):

We keep integrating the inequality $\cos x\le x$, for $x\ge 0$, in the interval $[0,x]$, and we recursively obtain
$$
\cos x \le 1\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\sin x \le x\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
1-\cos x \le \frac{x^2}{2!}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
1- \frac{x^2}{2!}\le\cos x \quad\Longrightarrow\quad
x-\frac{x^3}{3!}\le \sin x\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^4}{4!}\le 1-\cos x\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\cos x\le 1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad\cdots
$$
In general, continuing this we obtain
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!}\le\cos x\le \sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!}
$$
Note that it holds, not only for $x\ge 0$, but for $x<0$, since all the functions above are even.