# Prove that $1-\frac{x^2}{2}<\cos{x}<1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification, inequality

Prove that $1-\frac{x^2}{2}<\cos{x}<1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}$ and $x \in (0,\pi/2]$

Proof:

for $1-\frac{x^2}{2}<\cos{x}$

$\implies 1<\frac{x^2}{2}+\cos{x}$

Then, by mean value theorem

$\cos{x} +x^2/2 - 1 = (-\sin{c} +c)(x)$

$\implies \cos{x} -x^2/2 - 1 >0$ ( I put the lower bound on this)

and hence the inequality follows.

for $\cos{x}<1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}$

$\implies \cos{x}+\frac{x^2}{2} -\frac{x^4}{24}<1$

Again, by MVT, we have that:

$\cos{x}+\frac{x^2}{2} -\frac{x^4}{24} -1 = (-\sin{c} +c -\frac{c^3}{6})(x)$

I don't know how to proceed any further. Can anyone please help and also verify the first part of the inequality?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that if $0&lt;\theta&lt;\frac\pi2$, then $1-\frac{\theta^2}2&lt;\cos\theta&lt;1-\frac{\theta^2}2+\frac{\theta^4}{24}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2783301/prove-that-if-0-theta-frac-pi2-then-1-frac-theta22-cos-theta1-frac)

Comment: Duplicate: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2783301/prove-that-if-0-theta-frac-pi2-then-1-frac-theta22-cos-theta1-frac/2783358#2783358

Comment: I saw the post. However, I'm interested in knowing what i've done is right or wrong and doing the second inequality using just the MVT instead of employing the notion of limits, series or power series etc. Can you help?